# Saving one to many entity with relation Id

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api, entity-framework-core

I need to create an entity with relation id. When i try to save an entity, it is saved correctly. But when i read from DB, it is wrong

Models:

```
public class Food
{
    public long Id { get; set; }
    
    [MaxLength(255)]
    public string Name { get; set; } = "";
    
    public long? MenuId { get; set; }
    public Menu Menu { get; set; }

}

public class Menu
{
    public long Id { get; set; }
    
    [MaxLength(255)]
    public string Name { get; set; } = "";
    
    public ICollection<Food> Foods { get; set; }
}
```

Controllers:

```
[HttpGet]
public async Task<ActionResult<IEnumerable<Food>>> Getfoods()
{
    return await _context.Foods.ToListAsync();
}

[HttpPost]
public async Task<ActionResult<Food>> PostFood([FromBody] Food food)
    {
        var menu = await _context.Menus.FindAsync(food.MenuId);
        food.Menu = menu;
        
        _context.Entry(food).State = EntityState.Added;
        // await _context.Foods.AddAsync(food);
        await _context.SaveChangesAsync();

        return CreatedAtAction(nameof(GetFood), new { food.Id }, food);
    }
```

The food entity:

```json
{
  "name": "food1",
  "menuId": 1
}
```

My post controller returns what I wanted:

```json
{
  "id": 1,
  "name": "food1",
  "menuId": 1,
  "menu": {
           "id": 1,
           "name": "menu1",
           "foods": []
          }
}
```

But when i get the foods, menu is null:

```json
[
  {
    "id": 1,
    "name": "food1",
    "menuId": 1,
    "menu": null
  }
]
```

Comment: You need to `.Include` the menu entity with the query. Or fetch it separately. [Read the docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/related-data/)

Comment: Thank you, i feel like a stupid

Answer (score 0):

I forget to add `.Include` on GetFoods Controller